# How to prevent Jquery mobile from adding DIV automatically?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm using JQM for a mobile site.

I have this HTML:

```
<input readonly="readonly" type="text" 
       id="countdown" size="3" value="150" style="width: 50px" />
```

here is the screenshot

[image]

When I check with inspection tool I see this:

```
<div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset">
<input readonly="readonly" type="text" 
       id="countdown" size="3" value="150" style="width: 50px">
</div>
```

The strange part I see nothing when I view the source.

How can I solve this? It should only be 50 px wide, but the div behhind make it look wider.

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zxq9rpvf/)

Answer (score 1):

I found out, you can turn off styling:

```
data-role="none"
```

Which get me the desired size, but I still wanted the style.

Someone let me know if there is a better alternative.